# Build a model to predict exam score based on previous exam scores - handle missing data

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, data-imputation

I'm building a prediction model to predict students' exam scores of the current course, based on the exam scores of the previous courses they have taken. The thing is, not every student has the same learning path, so the previous courses vary. I have already tried to choose the previous courses that have as much students taken as possible, but still there are many missing records for each column of the previous score that I can't simply remove. Replacing with 0 also doesn't seem right, as it indicates the student fails the previous course. I have the students' current GPA, and I'm thinking of classifying the GPA into several bins and imputing the missing scores using the mean score of each bin for each previous course. Is there any better solution to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to cluster different courses by merging the ones that are similar in term of topics or scientific area. This way you should be able to reduce the distortion introduced by imputing the average gpa to courses that a given student did not take due to the level of difficulty. Then you could also creat an indicator for each scientific area that shows how many courses the students has taken in that area, and maybe weight the score of a given student in a given area by that indicator.